# logging seems to have memory leak for multi-thread usage

Tags: python, multithreading

I meet one scenario of memory leak in Python, I guess it's related with logging module for multi-thread, but I don't find why.

Version1 (With memory-leak and multi-thread call)

```
campaign_id_queue = Queue.Queue()
campaign_worker = {} # it has data inside, key is ID, value is Class object
for campaign_id, worker in campaign_worker.iteritems():
    campaign_id.queue.put(campaign_id)

thread_list = []
for n in range(THREAD_NUM): # defined already
    thread_list.append( Thread(target=parallel_run, args=(campaign_id_queue, now, n, logger)))

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
campaign_id_queue.join()

# another file
def parallel_run(campaign_id_queue, now, n, logger):
    while True:
        try:
            campaign_id = campaign_id_queue.get()
        except Queue.Empty:
            logger.warning('Queue empty')
        else:
            try:
                if worker.open_clients(logger) < 0:
                    logger.error('error here')
                    continue
                worker.run(now, logger)
            except Exception, e:
               logger.exception(e)
            finally:
               campaign_id_queue.task_done()
```

Version2 (Without memory-leak and single-thread call)

```
campaign_worker = {} # it has data inside, key is ID, value is Class object
for campaign_id, worker in campaign_worker.iteritems():
    if worker.open_clients(logger) < 0:
        logger.error('error here')
        continue
    worker.run(now, logger)
```

Comment: Post some minimal code that actually works and demonstrates what you consider to be the error (what you posted appears to have errors e.g. `campaign_work` and then `campaign_worker`). Say what it is about it that leads you to believe there is a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's my spelling mistake here. I think it's memory leak because I check this part of code (it's in an infinite loop as a service), it leads to memory increases of Process with version1, but if I change it to version2, no memory increases happened

Answer (score 0):

It's related with thread not killed after use, not related with logging module, it's solved now, thanks for attention.